# string generated from c# into view of MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a custom validator at class level in my MVC appications's model.
So inside the custom validator I am generating the error message based on the conditions and tryint to return to the MVC and assign it to summary list as below.
Model name is "Insured" here

```
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
            string errorMessage = "";
           //StringBuilder errorMessage1 = new StringBuilder();

            var model = value as Insured;
            if (model == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("No valid Session exists.");
            }
            else
            {
                if (model.Age > 19)
                  errorMessage += " <li> Age cannot be greater than 19. </li> " + Environment.NewLine;

            }
      return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
    }
```

And so on adding all the text to errormessage string.But when i display it on the page it is displaying everything in one line instead of displaying each one in next line sunce I am using Environment.NewLine.

I tried with `<br/>` \n\r and so on but everything is displayed as a text instead of html.

I tried to use string builder also.

Displaying: `<li> Age cannot be greater than 19. </li><li> Another error. </li>`

instead of

Age cannot be greater than 19.

Another error.

EDIT:
When i go into HTML by editing from firebug and just give a space inside generated error message everything getting aligned perfectly alright. This is so wierd, dont understand the issue.

Comment: Have you added `<ul></ul>` tags around it?

Comment: Have you tried &lt;br&gt; for <br> ?

Comment: Even if i dont use li in my string also it is displaying in same line.because of using break it should be displayed in next line

Comment: Yes I have used &lt;br&gt; for <br>                                 result: Age cannot be greater than 19. &lt;br&gt; Another error

Comment: @user1882705 show the relevant part of your view

Comment: http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/asp-net-mvc-lessthan-and-greaterthan-validation-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

Try HtmlString instead of string

```
new System.Web.HtmlString(" <li> Age cannot be greater than 19. </li> ");
```